# Accessing Database using JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am learning JSP and I want to create a table in mysql using JSP. I have the following code.

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
    <%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>MySQL Database creation</title>
    <style>
      { font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Creation of a books database</h2>

    <jsp:declaration>

    Statement stmt;
    Connection con;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

    </jsp:declaration>

    <jsp:scriptlet><![CDATA[

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", ""); 

    stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE books");
    con.close();

    ]]></jsp:scriptlet>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and my error.jsp page is

```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>

   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Error page</title>
   <style>
     { font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h2>Error occured!</h2>
   <p>Message 
   <jsp:expression> 
        exception.getMessage() 
   </jsp:expression>
   </p>

   </body>
   </html>
```

When I run it, it is getting redirected to error page and getting the output as below:

Error occured!
Message com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to place the code inside of servlet.  Generally it is not good practice to interject code into your html or view layer.

Comment: First thing , scriptlets are **EVIL** , Next , did you add the driver jar in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: which jar I have to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>MySQL Database creation</title>
<style>
  { font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Creation of a books database</h2>

<jsp:declaration>

Statement stmt;
Connection con;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your database name";

</jsp:declaration>

<jsp:scriptlet><![CDATA[

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", ""); 

stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE `test`.`sample` (`id` TINYINT UNSIGNED), `name` VARCHAR (50)");
con.close();

]]></jsp:scriptlet>
```

Comment: <%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Obtaining a Connection </title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet result=null;
Statement stmt=null;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd=null;
try {
  Class c=Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
catch(Exception e){
  out.write("Error!!!!!!" + e);
}
try {
  conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mystudyr_vshare1",
   "mystudyr_test","passw0rd");
  out.write("Connected!");
}
catch(SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("Error!!!!!!" + e);
}
%>
</body>
</html> wen i tried this, i am getting 404 error

Comment: copy and paste run this before that change username password and database name  <%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Obtaining a Connection </title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
<% Connection conn=null; 
ResultSet result=null; 
Statement stmt=null;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd=null;
try { 
    Class c=Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test", "root","root");
    out.write("Connected!"); }
catch(SQLException e) 
{ 
    System.out.println("Error!!!!!!" + e);
  } %>
    </body> 
</html>

Comment: jar file...is it just copy paste or something more?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java) in this link follow the method 2 to add jar file

Answer (score 1):

Jsp for front end so please avoid database code here

**solution for you**

add jar file [download](https://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&can=2&q=)

```
mysqlconnecter.jar
```

Comment: i downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.1.18-bin.jar and placed it in web-inf/lib and run it. Now, I am getting 404 error

Comment: that is what i downloaded.

Comment: restart your server and run

Comment: when u getting this error..stop your tomcat server and then run

Comment: 500 is a database error please check your database connection

Comment: create database externally and change String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your database name"; instead of creating database create table in your query

Answer (score 0):

friend after downloading your mysqlconnector you should provide the mysqlconnector path to jdk.